# If the sun stopped shining, could we survive?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction

As much as some people say that the sun is evil, it is a very important source of energy to us, so that if we concentrated 1% of the sun's power, we could power the whole world during 50 years.

If the sun spontaneously stopped shining in this instant, could we get away, go to another solar system for energy from that sun? Or could we just survive in bunkers or something?

Comment: Begging your pardon, Dutch, but having sun EXPLODED is not the same question as having the sun STOP SHINING. Agree to close question, but that is not a good reason why.

Comment: Hello, but I do not know why I am unable to delete my question since it says that people have invested time and effort into it.

Comment: Dario, there are existing comments and an answer to the question. Deleting or altering it now will lead to punitive measures, I got myself kicked for a week for doing exactly that. DON'T! Just back away and write-off the experience.

Comment: @PcMan, based on OP's comment on Mike's answer they meant exactly that: what I meant is the type of sun explosion where it just runs out of hydrogen, and then we have no solar light left.  If the sun just stopped shining in this instant, what would happen?

Comment: Sun is destined to turn into red giant in a couple of billions of years, then we would be gone (somewhere hopefully). Fortunately it doesn't have sufficient mass to go supernova so please do not worry and no need to panic ;D

Comment: Ok I edited it. Now it is correct. Hope that makes you happy.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186096/earth-was-suddenly-teleported-away-from-the-sun-can-we-recover/186122?r=SearchResults#186122

Answer (score 3):

Since to the best of our knowledge our sun couldn’t explode, it’s difficult to be sure what kind of explosion you have in mind. But the simple answer is no: If the sun were to go nova (which it can’t), it would sterilise the Earth. No bunker could be deep enough.  And we have no way to go to another solar system.

Comment: Hello, I understand your point of view, but what I meant is the type of sun explosion where it just runs out of hydrogen, and then we have no solar light left.

Comment: @DarioCastro That would be the opposite of an explosion.

Comment: @DarioCastro: That is not an "explosion" and the Sun will take billions of years to run out of fuel. We have no idea if humanity will still be around then, let alone if they'll be able to move to another star.

Comment: Ok, let my question be clearer... If the sun just stopped shining in this instant, what would happen?

Comment: @DarioCastro https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107166/humans-surviving-on-surface-without-sun